# Why did this assignment of a shared pointer have no effect after returning from nested function?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this mwe:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    shared_ptr<vector<int>> b;
};

void foo(vector<A> &vec)
{
    auto c = shared_ptr<vector<int>>(new vector<int>{42});
    vec.back().b = c;
    cout << "Foo size " << vec.back().b->size() << endl;
}

void bar(A &a)
{
    auto vec = vector<A>{a};
    foo(vec);
}


int main()
{
    A a;
    bar(a);
    cout << "Main size" << a.b->size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the program's output:

```
~ ./a.out                
Foo size 1
[1]    107400 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Why does `a.b->size()` yield in a segfault, instead of asking the vector which contains 42 to report its size?

Background: I have only very superficial knowledge of C++. Usually I program in Python but recently (some weeks ago) I started working on someone else's C++ code base and added some features to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()`, `a.b` doesn't point at a valid `vector`, so accessing `a.b->size()` is *undefined behavior*.

`bar()` creates a new `vector` that holds a *copy* of the `A` object that was passed in to it. `foo()` is then acting on that *copied* `A` object, not the original `A` object in `main()`.

If you want `foo()` to act on the original `A` object in `main()`, you will have to change `bar()` to pass a `vector<A*>` instead to `foo()`, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    shared_ptr<vector<int>> b;
};

void foo(vector<A*> &vec)
{
    auto c = shared_ptr<vector<int>>(new vector<int>{42});
    vec.back()->b = c;
    cout << "Foo size " << vec.back()->b->size() << endl;
}

void bar(A &a)
{
    auto vec = vector<A*>{&a};
    foo(vec);
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    bar(a);
    cout << "Main size" << a.b->size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` and other standard containers always store copies of objects.

When you do `auto vec = vector<A>{a};`, `a` is copied into the vector, so any changes to the vector don't affect `a`.

Comment: Is there a way to store references in a vector? Or is a design change needed?

Comment: @user3389669 to (safely) store references in a vector (or any container), you would have to use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). Otherwise, just store pointers instead.